# facing issue with google chrome

Tags: dpkg, google-chrome, software-uninstall

I can't find Chrome or uninstall it.

[image]

Comment: Please copy/paste instead of using screenshots. We cannot copy text or error messages from a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

1. In terminal, run

> `dpkg --list`
> 2. Find the chrome package, with search:
> `/chrome`
> 3. Copy the name of the package, some like:
> `google-chrome-stable`
> 4. And finally remove:
> `run apt --purge remove pkg-name`
> 5. May be something:
> `run apt --purge remove google-chrome-stable`

Comment: I forget, afterwards this procedure try install again!

Comment: Thanks brother. But not working.